# How to simplify nested expression $\sqrt[3]{p + \sqrt q} + \sqrt[3]{p - \sqrt q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the given expression
$$\sqrt[3]{a + \frac{a + 8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a - 1}{3}}} + \sqrt[3]{a - \frac{a + 8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a - 1}{3}}}$$

Are there any hints to do this? I have no idea

Answer (score 2):

The nested root is confusing (to me), so write $b^2=\frac{a-1}{3}$. Then

$$\begin{align}
a + \frac{a + 8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a - 1}{3}}&=1+3b+3b^2+b^3\text{,}\\
a - \frac{a + 8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a - 1}{3}}&=\ldots\text{.}
\end{align}$$
What is the cube root of $1+3b+3b^2+b^3$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that: $$ (a-b) = (\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b})(\sqrt[3]{a^2}-\sqrt[3]{ab}+\sqrt[3]{b^2}) $$

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$x=\sqrt[3]{a + \frac{a + 8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a - 1}{3}}} + \sqrt[3]{a - \frac{a + 8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a - 1}{3}}}$$

Take the cubic power of both sides

$$x^3= 2a + 3\left[a^2-\left(\frac{a+8}{3}\right)^2\left(\frac{a-1}{3}\right)\right]^{\frac13}x$$

Simplify the cubic-root term to get,

$$x^3-(4-a)x-2a=0$$

or,

$$(x-2)(x^2+2x+a)=0$$

which yields $x=2$. Thus, the original expression simplifies to

$$\sqrt[3]{a + \frac{a + 8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a - 1}{3}}} + \sqrt[3]{a - \frac{a + 8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a - 1}{3}}}=2$$